# How to split row into two rows in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I get a row, which contains non-zero values in two columns: `FixHours` and `AddHours`:

```
FixHours | AddHours | CalculatedValue
---------+----------+----------------
     0,5 |      1,5 |            16.5
```

How can I split it into two rows such as:

```
FixHours | AddHours | CalculatedValue
---------+----------+----------------
     0,5 |        0 |            16.5
       0 |      1,5 |            16.5
```

I have had an idea to find that row and artificially make a second row using the `union` operator. But I have many rows with values in two columns at the same time. Any ideas?

Comment: add your table defentition, example data and your query to question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, I think something like this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT FixHours, AddHours, CalculatedValue
FROM tbl
WHERE FixHours = 0
OR AddHours = 0

UNION

SELECT FixHours, 0, CalculatedValue
FROM tbl
WHERE FixHours <> 0
AND AddHours <> 0

UNION

SELECT 0, AddHours, CalculatedValue
FROM tbl
WHERE FixHours <> 0
AND AddHours <> 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
select
 case when x=1 THEN 0 ELSE fixHours END as fixHours,
 case when x=2 THEN 0 ELSE addHours END as addHours,
 calculatedValue
from input
 cross join (select 1 as x UNION select 2 as x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT FixHours, 0 AS AddHours, CalculatedValue
FROM table
UNION
SELECT 0, AddHours, CalculatedValue
FROM table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Split.FixHours
      ,Split.AddHours
      ,YourTable.CalculatedValue
FROM YourTable
     CROSS APPLY (
         VALUES (FixHours, 0), (0, AddHours)
     ) AS Split(FixHours, AddHours)
```

Comment: This would be a better-quality answer if it included an explanation of why it works.